# Call forwarded to Nexmo number don't get trough to Restcomm

Tags: restcomm

I have a Nexmo DID that points to Restcomm cloud. If I call this number it get to my Restcomm app fine.
BUT if I setup a call forward on my phone and call my phone number, the call is forwarded to the Nexmo DID and then I get a 'That number doesn't exist' message.
I think the issue is that there must be a confusion between my Phone number and the Nexmo number and Restcomm look at my number which it doesn't know instead of the Nexmo number...
Any idea how to get this to work?
Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Did you try adding your phone number as Phone Number in Restcomm tied to your application ?

Comment: Yep. Didn't help. Actually, I discovered while testing it that using a fixed line the Nexmo number didn't work even when called directly... It seems not to have proper interco with some Operators in France!